# Reals constructed from equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences of rationals.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, real-numbers

Is it proper to say (as I keep reading) that the real numbers are "equal" to the equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences in the completion of the rational numbers.  Yes, there is a one-to-one correspondence with the limits of the sequences, but "equal to" seems too strong.
Am I correct in this?

Comment: Yes, this is how real numbers have been constructed.

Comment: So, given a real number $r$ there is a cauchy sequence of rational numbers that converges to $r$.

Comment: But why not say reals are equal to the limit of those sequences?  To say a single real number is "equal to" a class of sets seems like an unnecessary mix of apples and oranges.

Comment: Whether they are strictly *equal* depends on your particular choice of definitions. They are however isomorphic in pretty much every nice sense you can think of (as ordered fields, as metric spaces, ...), regardless of your choice of definitions.

Comment: Note that people constructed different types of numbers in the following order. 1)natural numbers  2)integers  3)rational numbers  and finally real numbers. After constructing rationals they found that there are sequences of rationals that approaches values which are not rational (today we called them irrationals). This motivates to construct real numbers like this.

Comment: You say that this is Apple and Orange, both multinational corporations by the way, but let me ask you this. What is a real number, formally?

Comment: Think of a real number as a decimal expansion. Oh, oops, that's a Cauchy sequence! It took centuries to find a suitable, rigorous definition of a real number; now it's just assumed to exist. It was a stroke of genius to define the thing that nobody could find by the process used to find it. You can use Dedekind cuts or equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences, and both are defined by what is missing. Defining real numbers as the unique complete Archimedean ordered field doesn't help unless you can show that such a thing exists.

Answer (score 2):

There are several possible construction of the real numbers that, in the usual framework of set theory (ZFC or equivalent) give rise to isomorphic structures.

It doesn't matter how the real numbers are constructed, so long as they are an archimedean ordered field $F$ which is Cantor-complete (if $S$ and $T$ are non empty subsets of $F$ such that $s\le t$, for all $s\in S$ and $t\in T$, then there exists $r\in F$ such that $s\le r\le t$, for all $s\in S$ and $t\in T$).

Two such structures are isomorphic in a strong sense: there is a *unique* field isomorphism between them. In particular they can't be told apart by just using properties of ordered fields. Moreover there is a unique embedding of the rational numbers in such a field.

The fact that one is the set of equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences in the rationals and the other is, maybe, the set of Dedekind cuts of the rationals is completely irrelevant, as far as the theory of real numbers is concerned. One just uses their properties summarized above.

If you like to think that a real number is an equivalence class of Cauchy sequences, you're welcome, but it really adds nothing to your understanding of the real numbers. The constructions are important because with them we know we're talking about something.

Such a field can be given a uniformity which makes it into a topological field (the operations are continuous), so a notion of Cauchy net can be given (that doesn't appeal to the real numbers) and it can be proved that this uniform space is complete, that is, every Cauchy net converges. In particular (using the unique embedding of the rationals mentioned above), every Cauchy sequence of rationals converges.

Comment: Cantor complete? Is that a thing?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Why not?

Comment: No reason, I just don't recall hearing that term before. Dedekind complete, sure. But Cantor complete?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Dedekind's and Cantor's conditions are slightly different, but equivalent for Archimedean ordered fields.

Comment: If I recall my history right, Dedekind gave his constructions via cuts, and Cantor gave his via Cauchy sequences.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Cantor published his definition (with Cauchy sequences) in 1871, Dedekind (with cuts) in 1872. I couldn't find the date of Weierstrass' paper for his definition with decimal alignments, but IIRC it's in the same years.

Comment: Yes, that is what I remembered. But the definition you give for "Cantor complete" seems more akin to Dedekind complete. It has nothing to do with Cantor's suggestion to use Cauchy sequences.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I didn't say it has. It's a condition the set of real numbers should satisfy and Cantor posed it that way.

Comment: Do you have a handy reference for that?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sorry, no (and I have no time for looking up).  Here's something: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/808379/what-is-the-real-meaning-of-hilberts-axiom-of-completeness