# What is a link between the topological and order-theoretic completeness?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

Take $\mathbb{R}$ as an example.

Order-theoretically, the set $\mathbb{R}$ of all real numbers can be developed as a complete totally ordered field, where "complete" indicates that the supremum axiom is imposed.

On the other hand, the set $\mathbb{R}$ happens to be topologically complete, in the sense that every Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ converges in $\mathbb{R}$.

Is the order-theoretic completeness a notion developed independent of the concept of topological completeness, or is the converse true, or none of them is true? In general, what is a link between them?

Comment: The first is order-theoretic, not set-theoretic.

Comment: and the topology on $\mathbb R$ happens to be the order-topology ...

Comment: Thank you. I corrected them. @Ian

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: It seems that the present question is trivial to you. For some reason, not trivial to me.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: Thank you for your information. Don't get what your dots possibly mean.

Comment: See also this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/808379/what-is-the-real-meaning-of-hilberts-axiom-of-completeness).

Comment: Are you familiar with the notion of an order topology? An interesting question would be: if A is an ordered set, is there some interesting topological property P such that the order topology on A has property P iff the order is complete?

Comment: @NateEldredge: Thank you. I am new to that, indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two concepts are strictly linked through the modern definitions of [real number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number).

We have to consider [Cantor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georg_Cantor)'s definition, based on [Cauchy sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence), and [Dedekind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Dedekind)'s one, based on [Dedekind cuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_cut).

Several axioms has been proposed to ensure the so-called "completeness" like :

- [metric completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space) : every Cauchy sequence of points in a metric space $M$ has a limit in $M$
- [order-theoretic completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_(order_theory)).

See also [Construction of the real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_of_the_real_numbers), [Dedekind's Contributions to the Foundations of Mathematics](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/dedekind-foundations/) and [The Early Development of Set Theory](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/settheory-early/); both Cantor and Dedekind was at the origins of :

- foundations of analysis and definition of the structure of the set $\mathbb R$ of real numbers
- point set topology
- set theory.

Answer (score 0):

Well we have something called the order topology which we define on a totally ordered set. It can be thought of as the generalization of the standard topology given on $\Bbb{R}$.

You can read about order topology here : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrderTopology.html

Comment: How is this an answer to the question?

Answer (score -1):

In high school you learn to work with the system ${\mathbb Q}$ of rational numbers, or with the smaller system ${\mathbb D}$ of finite (binary or) decimal fractions. While these systems are unproblematic for daily business they are unsatisfactory from a mathematical standpoint: Many important numbers that we know should be there, are missing; e.g., ${1\over3}\notin{\mathbb D}$, $\sqrt{2}\notin{\mathbb Q}$, etcetera.

There are various "bigtime" abstract constructions that fill in these holes, so that a homogeneous continuum of real numbers ${\mathbb R}$ results.

One such construction uses "Dedekind cuts" and produces a system ${\mathbb R}_{\rm Ded}$ that is so called *order complete*. Another construction uses "Cauchy sequences" and produces a system ${\mathbb R}_{\rm Cau}$ that is  *metrically complete*.

Whichever approach you take, you can prove at the end that your ${\mathbb R}_{\rm Ded}$ is in fact also metrically complete, resp. that your ${\mathbb R}_{\rm Cau}$ is in fact also order complete – the reason being that  ${\mathbb R}_{\rm Ded}$ and ${\mathbb R}_{\rm Cau}$ are "isomorphic".